# C++/MFC How to copy multiple files from PC to WinCE (Mobile Device)?

Tags: c++, file-io, mfc, windows-ce, rapi

I am trying to copy entire directory including all the files and subdirectories inside from PC into WinCE (Mobile Device).

I am aware of the RAPI.DLL to control files within WinCE, but I doesn't seem to work between PC and WinCE. Neither the Win32 file control interface.

It would be appreciated if someone helps me to solve this puzzle.

Any open source wrapper class for reference would be fine as well.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy file to a device you have a few options:

1. Use RAPI.  This requires that ActiveSync is part of the CE OS and you have an active ActiveSync/WMDC connection to the device.
2. Use a server on the device like FTP.  This requires that the server is in the OS, enabled and configured.
3. Use a network share to copy to the device.  This requires that the device OS has CIFS/SMB to allow the PC to find and push data to the device.
4. Use a proprietary protocol using HTTP/TCP or whatever.  This requires that the device has a "listener" service or application running.

Note how every one of these requires something be on the device and set up to allow the PC to interact with the device.  Which one(s) will work is highly dependent on your specific OS configuration.